# How to make Notification Center bar sticky?

Tags: mojave, notifications

I'd like to make [Notification Center](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204079) bar to be sticky (on-top, present all time), so it won't close automatically when clicking away.

I've checked System Preferences, but I couldn't find any option to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sticky, but the easiest way I could find to reach Notification Centre is to set up a hot corner in the top right. System Preferences → Mission Control, Hot corners.

[image: Mission Control Settings]